# Android Studio, Layout, round corners, different background color

Tags: android, layout

I'm creating a XML file to use as the custom info windows for markers in the google maps.

I'm struggling to achieve the round corner. I found different solutions. Or use a `CardView`, or create a background using shapes and give it round corners and use it as background for my layout and so on. But every solution I found, gives you only a single color per background.

My layout has split in two. The top half, the title and bottom half for more specific information and I want to give them two different background color.

If I use a `CardView` or shape, I can't give them a different background color. If I set a background color for specific elements, the background color stays over the round corner layout and a rectangular-no-round-corner, cover the round corner.

How can I manage this? any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You might consider doing this programmatically if the requirement is highly dynamic. You can use an `ImageView`, `CardView` or whatever you may like and set the background shape and color programmatically wherever necessary like the following.

```
public static GradientDrawable drawCircle(int backgroundColor, int borderColor) {
    GradientDrawable shape = new GradientDrawable();
    shape.setShape(GradientDrawable.OVAL);
    shape.setCornerRadii(new float[]{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0});
    shape.setColor(backgroundColor);
    shape.setStroke(10, borderColor);
    return shape;
}
```

Now set the background in your view (i.e. an `ImageView`) like the following.

```
imageView.setBackground(drawCircle(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_blue_dark), getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_red_dark)));
```